# Python - mapping over a sparse matrix

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am working with a csr_matrix (from scipy.sparse) and I need to apply a logarithm-like function on all its items.

> f:x->log(x+1), so f(0)=0).

What would be the efficient way of doing that ?

I could not found any map function for csr_matrix, do I have forgotten one ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about (specifically for this function) `log1p`?

See the scipy documentation: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.log1p.html

Comment: Exactly what I needed !

Comment: `sparse.data._ufuncs_with_fixed_point_at_zero` is the list of `ufuncs` that are implemented this way.